# Swift - Reorder UITableView cells

Tags: swift

I do know that it's not too hard to do it in objective C , the problem is I'm learning Swift by skipping Objective C.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html

However is there anything equivalent to the link above in Swift?

Comment: You can call Objective-C from Swift.

Comment: Hi zneak, like pure Objective-C no need for wrappers?

Comment: Yes, pure Objective-C without wrappers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have tried this...here is the code

In my example code there is button that starts the editing ---
Action Method of the button -->

```
@IBAction func editTableView (sender:UIBarButtonItem)
{
    if listTableView.editing{
        //listTableView.editing = false;
        listTableView.setEditing(false, animated: false);
        barButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain;
        barButton.title = "Edit";
        //listTableView.reloadData();
    }
    else{
        //listTableView.editing = true;
        listTableView.setEditing(true, animated: true);
        barButton.title = "Done";
        barButton.style =  UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done;
        //listTableView.reloadData();
    }
}
```

And the related UITableView delegate methods -->

```
// The editing style for a row is the kind of button displayed to the left of the cell when in editing mode.

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle
        {
            if (false == self.editing && !indexPath){
                return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None;
            }

            if (self.editing && indexPath.row == countryList.count){
                return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Insert;
            }
            else{
                return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete;
            }
            //return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete;
        }

        // Update the data model according to edit actions delete or insert.
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
        {
            if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete{
                countryList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row);
                self.editTableView(barButton);
                listTableView.reloadData();
            }
            else if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Insert{
                countryList.append("New Country");
            }
        }


        // Determine whether a given row is eligible for reordering or not.
       func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Process the row move. This means updating the data model to correct the item indices.
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath!, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath!)
        {
            let item : String = countryList[sourceIndexPath.row];
            countryList.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row);
            countryList.insert(item, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
        }
```

You can also **download full code** [Here](https://github.com/suryakants/TableViewOperationInSwift)

Comment: One question I have is, I have a button, does it have to be barButtonItem?

Comment: in that case, you have to change in some places like UIBarButton to UIButton

Comment: Great thanks, i was wondering if there's a way for me to change the text of a UIButton?

Comment: of-course you can change UIButton title by `setTitle(title: String?, forState: <#UIControlState#>)`

Comment: I get error in if (false == self.editing && !indexPath); // == overload not found.
There are 7 errors in the source code as well, kindly provide an updated one
Appreciate the effort

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sample. I need to display the reordered rows when i quit and run the app. Any ideas to achieve this.

Comment: @Apple when user reorder your `UITableView', you need to reorder the datasource as well to retain that reordering thing.

Comment: @sharma,i have used NSUserDefaults for storing the source and destination indexpath. In viewDidLoad how can i display my cells in according to the stored values. Am i going in a correct way ?

Comment: @Apple I really didn't get what you're trying. Can you explain?

Comment: but let me tell you one thing, if you want the reordering thing to be there next time you reload/load your `UITableView` you need to update your datasource, according to reordering performed by user

Answer (score 11):

All the same rules apply as in Objective-C. You set the table view data source and delegate just like you would in Objective-C.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    return true // Yes, the table view can be reordered
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath!, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    // update the item in my data source by first removing at the from index, then inserting at the to index.
    let item = items[fromIndexPath.row]
    items.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
    items.insert(item, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)
}
```

If you need finer grain control, you can also implement

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath!, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> NSIndexPath! {
    …
}
```

Comment: Do I need to update tableView or have this aTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([fromIndexPath.row], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

Comment: @Marin the table view already knows about the update when `tableView(,moveRowAtIndexPath, toIndexPath)` is called. All you need to do is update your data source to match the update in the table view.

Comment: The code works but nothing happens... for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Now there is a library for this reorder function: [LPRTableView](https://github.com/nicolasgomollon/LPRTableView).

Answer (score 0):

**Converted Above Answer methods in Swift 3.0**

```
    // Determine whether a given row is eligible for reordering or not.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            return true
    }


    // Process the row move. This means updating the data model to correct the item indices.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item : Dictionary<String, Any> = arrInterval[sourceIndexPath.row]
        arrInterval.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        arrInterval.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
```