# Swift 3 - Changing Order of Rows in Static TableView Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to change the order of a particular group of cells in a particular section of UITableView with static content.  I am trying to do this before the view loads, but for some reason I cannot get it to work.

I have tried creating reference outlets for each of the cells and then calling tableView.moveRow by calling in tableView.indexPath(for: cell1

I have also tried giving each a tag and looping through the cells in that section and reordering with with no success.

I have tried:

```
// Moving the row from it's default row
self.tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 1), to: IndexPath(row: newRow, section: 1))

// Creating a reference outlet called cell1
self.tableView.moveRow(at: self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell1)!, to: IndexPath(row: newRow, section: 1))

// Giving the static cell a reuseidentifier in interface builder
self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: IndexPath(row: self.subwayOrder+1, section: 1))
```

Comment: As said you are trying to do it before view loads, you should try doing this in ViewDidLoad method as Apple doc says this method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy  in memory. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621495-viewdidload.  As the view is not in memory your above code doesn't work.

Comment: I am doing this in viewDidLoad(), none of them seem to work though

Comment: Is this implemented   `func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool` and the change in data structure should happen in delegate method `func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath!, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath!)`. Also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772457/swift-reorder-uitableview-cells

Comment: Static tables are a built-in feature, and I doubt it's implemented by `UITableView`. I don't see how you can tell the controller that the order has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could possibly have success switching index paths in `cellForRow` by calling super's implementation.

Comment: This worked with a big of a work-around. I had to implement cellForRowAt but instead of using dequeue cell with reuse identifier I had to just return my references to each cell

Comment: I didn't suggest to dequeue though. Only to call super. Did that not work?

Comment: No you are completely right. Sorry I'm new to Swift and iOS, I had assumed that I needed to dequeue cells if I was implementing cellForRowAt

Comment: In the case of static table view controllers I just think of `super` as having done everything for me, and I override as needed. It has worked so far. That also makes it pretty straightforward to add dynamic content in a separate section.