# Swift: Reorder Table Rows programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a TableViewController with rows that hold tasks. If a task has an attribute `task.done = 1` I want to move it at the bottom from the table.
I can't provide any code, because I have no doubt how to do this.

My idea was in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` using following code:

```
let element = tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tasks.insert(element, at: tasks.count)
```

The issue is, that this needs to be done after the table is loaded, because if the first row is `done = 1` for example, it will be moved to to bottom and will be processed at the end again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Reorder UITableView cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772457/swift-reorder-uitableview-cells)

Comment: Never modify the data model or the table in `cellForRowAt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can programmatically remove a row from UITableView and insert a row programmatically. Before doing the operations on the UITableView, make sure to remove/add a specific item to the data source array. Otherwise, it'll just crash.

If you want to simply move the rows, you can use the code below. You need to do it in the place where the array which holds the data source is updated.

```
tableView.moveRow(at: oldIndexPath, to: newIndexPath)
```

If you want to do delete and insert new objects into the array, you may try the method as shown below.

```
let element = tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPath, with: .automatic)

tasks.insert(element, at: tasks.count)
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: tasks.count, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

Comment: Why insert and delete? Use `moveRow`.

Comment: Thank you. I love moveRow better. Where do I do this? within the `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: In your task done definition add a didSet block. Called after your done is set.

Comment: @rmaddy Agreed..! Thanks for correcting me. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a beginUpdates-endUpdates block.Use func moveRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, to newIndexPath: IndexPath)

For example: Not tested

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
let element = tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
let  movingRowIndex = indexPath.row
tasks.insert(element, at: tasks.count)
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: movingRowIndex, inSection: 0)
var lastIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:tasks.count, inSection: 0)
self.tableView.moveRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, to newIndexPath: lastIndexPath)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: This doesn't compile and `begin-/endUpdates` is pointless for a single operation.

Comment: Doesn't this need to be in a for loop that checks against the done attribute?